# Permiting :firstname but not saving to DB with devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to permit :firstname when registering an account, but the params are not passed through, what am I doing wrong?

I have already migrated a :firstname string into the database

```rb
# protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute, :firstname])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute, :firstname])
  # end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do couple things:

1. Generate the `registrations controller`. You can do that with this command:

```
rails g devise:controllers users -c=registrations
```

2. In the `routes.rb` file, add this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

3. In the `registrations_controller.rb` permit the extra params:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname])
  end
end
```

Reference:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixes the issue!

Comment: @Timofey, I am glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

You already read this code, to do so you just need to uncomment `configure_sign_up_params` method and add your attributes to the `keys`, something like the code below.

```
# protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname])
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute, :firstname])
  # end
```

Comment: Following this up, not only uncomment this method, but uncomment the `before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]` at the top of the file too, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

We may have get some problem while using `sanitize` for custom attributes in devise. Please  follow this [Add Custom Attributes](https://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html)
.